# BeautifulSoup unable to parse Goa University site

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am working on a parsing project which require me to parse educational website. While doing so, my code is unable to parse [**University of Goa**](http://unigoa.ac.in) site. It does not return as expected.
My code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

hdrs = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0 (X11 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (\
    KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 52.0.2743.116 Safari / 537.36'}    

r = requests.get(url, verify=True, headers=hdrs)
result = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print(result)
```

It prints:

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
    document.location="https://www.unigoa.ac.in/result_redirect.php";
</script>
</head></html>
```

instead of raw html parsed tree. I tried passing explicity parser `lxml` and `html5lib` to BeautifulSoup but it also does not work as expected. Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That *is* the raw parsed html tree. Try saving that to an html file and opening it in a browser... (just to understand what it does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a session then parse and use the redirect url:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(hdrs)
    r = s.get("https://www.unigoa.ac.in")
    result = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    redirect = result.find("script").text.split("=")[1].strip('";\r\n')
    r2 = s.get(redirect)
    print(r2.text)
```

*r2.text* will give you the html you see on the home page.

Comment: I guess, you edited your answer. BTW, previous answer also solved my problem with `r2.content` instead of `r2.text`. thank you very much for quick response... :)

Comment: @OmPrakash, no worries, I just changed to .text as in python3 you would see the text properly formatted, with .content you would see a single byte string.

Comment: oh I see. I had no idea of this difference between `.text` and `.content`. thank you again.

Comment: @OmPrakash: See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)